# Ensure that model.matrix has same number of columns for train and test set

Tags: r

Is there a way to ensure that model matrix has the same number of columns for train and test set?

I tried the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

create_encoder <- function(x){
  cat_vars <- x[1, ] %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% names()
  labels_dic <- cat_vars %>% map(~x %>% pull(.) %>% levels) %>% 
    set_names(cat_vars)
  encode_test <- function(x){
    y <- x
    y[, cat_vars] <- cat_vars %>%
      map(~factor(x %>% pull(.), labels_dic[[.]]))
    y
  }
}

x_ent <- tibble(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x2 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c'))
x_pr <- tibble(x1 = c(5, 6, 7), x2 = c('a', 'b', 'a'))
x_ent <- x_ent %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
x_pr <- x_pr %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

y_ent <- c(2, 1, 3, 4)
y_pr <- c(6, 3, 2)

encode_test <- create_encoder(x_ent)
x_pr <- encode_test(x_pr)

x_mat_ent <- model.matrix(~., x_ent)
x_mat_pr <- model.matrix(~., x_pr)

x_mat_ent
x_mat_pr

x_mat_ent %>% dim()
x_mat_pr %>% dim()
```

If I don't use `encode_test`, `model.matrix` yields different number of columns for train and test set.

Is there a function that does this far way better?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the train dataframe as well in the function to get it's levels to set.

```
library(dplyr)

create_encoder <- function(test, train){
  cols <- sapply(test, is.character)
  test[cols] <- purrr::map2(test %>% select(where(is.character)), 
                     train %>% select(where(is.factor)), 
                     ~factor(.x, levels = levels(.y))
                    )
  test
}

x_ent <- tibble(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x2 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c'))
x_pr <- tibble(x1 = c(5, 6, 7), x2 = c('a', 'b', 'a'))
x_ent <- x_ent %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), factor))
x_pr <- create_encoder(x_pr, x_ent)
x_mat_ent <- model.matrix(~., x_ent)
x_mat_pr <- model.matrix(~., x_pr)

x_mat_ent %>% dim()
#[1] 4 4
x_mat_pr %>% dim()
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: Ok. That would be all in one function. But isn't there anything like python OneHotEncoder?

Comment: I don't know what python OneHotEncoder does.

Comment: sklearn module in python has the OneHotEncoder class, which gets the one-hot-encoding matrix and handles the labels of categorical variables easily. I haven't found so far an R function that makes one hot enconding automatically and that handles differences between the number of labels of a categorical variable in train and test set.

Comment: In case some columns of test are already factors, add the following two lines in the create_coder function: 

```
cols <- sapply(test, is.factor); 
test[cols] <- purrr::map(test |> select(where(is.factor)), as.character)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm assuming you don't mean dimension but just the number of columns, we expect number of rows to be different because the variable lengths are different.

I think this is a good example of tidyverse complicating something very simple to fix:

```
library(tidyverse)

x_ent <- tibble(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x2 = factor(c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), levels = letters[1:3]))
x_pr <- tibble(x1 = c(5, 6, 7), x2 = factor(c('a', 'b', 'a'), levels = letters[1:3]))

x_mat_ent <- model.matrix(~., x_ent)
x_mat_pr <- model.matrix(~., x_pr)

x_mat_ent %>% dim()
x_mat_pr %>% dim()
```

You can also do this more dynamically by concatenating and setting `levels` after the tibbles are created.

Edit:

Automated example

```
library(tidyverse)

x_ent <- tibble(x1 = runif(100), x2 = factor(rbinom(100, 100, 0.5))); 
x_pr <- tibble(x1 = runif(100), x2 = factor(rbinom(100, 500, 0.5)))
levs <- c(levels(x_ent$x2), levels(x_pr$x2))
levels(x_ent$x2) <- levs
levels(x_pr$x2) <- levs

x_mat_ent <- model.matrix(~., x_ent)
x_mat_pr <- model.matrix(~., x_pr)

x_mat_ent %>% dim()
x_mat_pr %>% dim()
```

With forcats:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(1)

x_ent <- tibble(x1 = runif(100), x2 = factor(rbinom(100, 100, 0.5))); 
x_pr <- tibble(x1 = runif(100), x2 = factor(rbinom(100, 500, 0.5)))

x_ent %<>% mutate(x2 = fct_expand(x2, lvls_union(list(x_ent$x2, x_pr$x2))))
x_pr %<>% mutate(x2 = fct_expand(x2, lvls_union(list(x_ent$x2, x_pr$x2))))

x_mat_ent <- model.matrix(~., x_ent)
x_mat_pr <- model.matrix(~., x_pr)

x_mat_ent %>% dim()
x_mat_pr %>% dim()
```

Comment: Yes. I mean same number of columns. I already edited the question so it is clear now. As regards your example, how could this be automatically done if the data set is bigger?

Comment: I've added a 2nd example to demonstrate this